# store the value of toggle button as 1 when it is on else 0 off in same array variable using php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have a toggle button like this inside a table where the button will be created dynamically based on number of rows fetched from the database

```
<td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" class="toggleone" name="attendance[]" id="attendance[]" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></td>
```

my problem is the values are not correctly posted when clicking on post button 
But the count of on buttons is correct but not stored correctly in their position

```
button             obtained output               desired output
on                    1                             1
off                   1                             0
off                   0                             0
off                   0                             0
on                    0                             1
```

Someone help me where i am going wrong.
Here is my for loop

```
for($i=0;$i<($_SESSION['num1']);$i++)
{

        $subcheck = (isset($_POST['attendance'][$i]))? 1 : 0;
        echo $subcheck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, `$_POST['attendance'][$i]` is not what you think it is. If 2 inputs are checked, the first 2 values of `$_POST['attendance']` will be set (indices 0 and 1), regardless of whether they are the first 2 checkboxes or for example the last 2.

As you don't set a key nor a value for your checkboxes, you will not be able to identify them on the server.

To avoid this, you should set the key manually when you build the form or give them a value.

To set the key in a loop, you can use something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggleone" name="attendance[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="attendance_<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No">
```

Note that I am not sure if you can use the array notation for the ID (I don't think so...) so I have set the ID using a string.

Comment: I found the solution by myself i iset the default value as 0 and updated it if it checked as 1 that worked out for me thanks a lot